# Problems with boolean statement and if statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, boolean, boolean-expression

```
def test():
    boo = True
    enter = int(raw_input("Enter something: "))
    if enter > 0:
        boo = False
        print "Did it work?!"
    else:
        print "Still working..."
    while boo == True:
        test()

test()
```

So this bit of code seems to only work if the first part of the if statement is met first try. 
aka if you  enter -1 then 1 it continues to loop through the function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Get a positive integer input from the user?

Comment: Is recursion intended?

Comment: Did you realize that your function is being called in a loop and [recursively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29)? That seems a bit odd.

Comment: It's a bit odd, but it makes for a decent chuckle, anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boo` is a *local* variable. Every time you recursively call `test()`, that recursive call gets a *new* local variable `boo` that is independent of all parent functions calling it. As such, it is set to `True` at the beginning of the function.

Your calls look like this:

- `test()`, `boo = True`, `enter` = 1, so `while boo == True` is true:

  - `test()`, `boo = True`, `enter` = -1, so `while boo == True` is false, returning

- at this level, `boo == True` is *still true*, so we call `test()` again.

  - `test()`, `boo = True`, `enter` = -1, so `while boo == True` is false, returning

etc. ad nauseum.

You want to *return* `boo`:

```
def test():
    boo = True
    enter = int(raw_input("Enter something: "))
    if enter > 0:
        boo = False
        print "Did it work?!"
    else:
        print "Still working..."
    while boo:
        boo = test()
    return boo
```

Now when `test()` returns, you set `boo` *in the calling function* to `False`.

Note that `== True` is redundant, just test for `boo` itself in `while boo`.

It is really not a good idea to use recursion for user input. Just use a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    enter = int(raw_input("Enter something: "))
    if enter < 0:
        print "Did it work?!"
        break
    print "Still working..."
```

Comment: (+1) but I think it would be great to show that recursion is completely unnecessary here and only serves to obscure the logic.

Comment: @NPE: I was busy adding a better option. I wanted to explain about where the OP had gone wrong first.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thanks. I am new to python and will definitely be reading up on recursion. I think putting everything into a while loop will help a lot.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for expanding the answer. I think it is great.

Answer (score 2):

Combining a potentially infinite `while` loop with a recursive function is a very dangerous game. When you get to subsequent calls of `test()`, even if they work and exit out right away, your original call to `test()` will still loop forever. `boo` is never changed in the original function call just because it's changed in later ones.

Your code could be fixed this way:

```
def test():
    boo = True
    enter = int(raw_input("Enter something: "))
    if enter > 0:
        boo = False
        print "Did it work?!"
    else:
        print "Still working..."
    if boo == True:
        test()
```

But it would be even better this way:

```
def test():
    enter = int(raw_input("Enter something: "))
    while enter <= 0:
        print "Still working..."
        enter = int(raw_input("Enter something: "))
    print "Did it work?!"
```